# HTML CSS Navbar Spacing

Tags: html, css, navbar, spacing

I made a CSS Navbar, but inbetween each "navbar-item", there is little space. I don't want there to be anyspace at all! Is there a way to make this happen without changing the margin-left for every navbar-item?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home - UnhandyFir9</title>
        <style>
            #wrapper {
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px black;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                margin: auto;
                margin-top: 30px;
                width: 800px;
                background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            #top-notification {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 20px;
                background-color: lightblue;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #navbar-core {
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                background-color: lightgreen;
            }
            #navbar-item {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: green;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <span id="top-notification">== Hi! Our site was just recently launched, so you may expect alot of bugs! Sorry 'bout that! ==</span>
            <div id="navbar-core">
                <a href="home.html" id="navbar-item">Home</a>
                <a href="lessons.html" id="navbar-item">Lessons</a>
                <a href="aboutus.html" id="navbar-item">About Us</a>
                <a href="donate.html" id="navbar-item">Donate</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: j08691: that doesn't affect rendering, all browsers will still apply the style correctly. It's a standards violation which will break validation of course, and incredibly mess up with Javascript.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - Did I say it affected rendering or would solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `display:inline-block` - it reduces the elements to inline blocks, meaning they behave like all other inline content in HTML. Since there's whitespace between the anchor elements, which as always collapses to a single whitespace, what you see is an actual 'space' in between in the current font size just like between words in a sentence. You can fix this by applying `font-size:0` on the container but that's messy since you'd have to reset it for the children. Recommended method is to just use `float:left` instead and manually set the parent's size correctly, and set the items to `height:100%`.

Using multiple elements with the same ID is wrong but not causing this issue - should still be fixed though.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, IDs must be unique, so use classes instead. That being said, your links are inline elements and are sensitive to white space, so either float them left or remove the white space between the elements in the code.

Ex:

```
.navbar-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r8pdV/)**

White space removed **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aFfhd/)**

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
#navbar-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Change this to a `class` instead of an `id`. `Id`'s are unique and can only be used once on a page but a class can be used over and over again.

I am pretty sure the space is from this but I will make a fiddle to test,

> display: inline-block;

You could change `display: inline-block;` to `float: left;` and have it without the space.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj254/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
.navbar-item {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

<div id="wrapper">
<span id="top-notification">== Hi! Our site was just recently launched, so you may expect alot of bugs! Sorry 'bout that! ==</span>
<div id="navbar-core">
<a href="home.html" class="navbar-item">Home</a>
<a href="lessons.html" class="navbar-item">Lessons</a>
<a href="aboutus.html" class="navbar-item">About Us</a>
<a href="donate.html" class="navbar-item">Donate</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block;` by using inline-block will have 4px margin by default but using `float: left;` by default do not have the space. And use classes for every `a element` no id, id are unique and shouldn't be repeated.

```
.navbar-item {
     /*display: inline-block;*/
     float: left;
     width: 100px;
     height: 30px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: green;
     color: white;
}
```

If you still want to use `inline-block` instead of `float: left;` you should use `margin-left: -4px;`

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem quickly, you can wrap your links with span and give it a darker background:

```
<div id="navbar-core">
    <span class="navbar-inner-wrapper">
            <a href="home.html" id="navbar-item">Home</a>
            <a href="lessons.html" id="navbar-item">Lessons</a>
            <a href="aboutus.html" id="navbar-item">About Us</a>
            <a href="donate.html" id="navbar-item">Donate</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar-inner-wrapper {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: You should not be trying to solve it quickly instead try to fix what is broken. -1